# Recursively find folder names only (not files)

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to display the folder names (only) recursively. I know, to display the files from the specific folder using the following command. 

`Dir.glob("/home/test/**/*.pdf")
or
Dir['/home/test/**/*.*']`

But, i need to display folder name only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you put a slash, like this

```
Dir["**/"].each {|x| puts x}
```